# Adding an image texture to a mesh

Tags: image, texture-painting

I have a body mesh that's already UV unwrapped and has a skin texture, I want to add a transparent background image to it instead of texture painting on it, can this be done somehow?

Comment: Hello what does it mean, you want to add a transparent background instead of the skin texture? Does it mean that the skin is supposed to be transparent? Please add details

Comment: I would like to add the transparent image on top of the skin one to make it look like body paint or tattoo.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare your tatoo image on a transparent background, mix it with the skin color in a *Color > Mix Color* node, use the *Alpha* output as a factor:

[image]

If the tatoo is supposed to have another shader, mix 2 shaders into a *Mix Shader* instead, like that:

[image]

Comment: I'll try that, thank you so much!